# Filter a data frame by part of name in column

Tags: r, data-representation

Here's my example below.

```
Name <- c("HU-5-A", "HU-6-C", "CE-5-A", "LE-3-C", "LE-4-A", "CE-9-B")
x <- c(rnorm(6))
y <- c(rnorm(6))
df <- data.frame(cbind(Name, x, y))
```

I'd like to filter my df but by only common part in the `Name` column so the result will be

```
Name         x         y
LE-3-C 0.6087576 2.3199352
LE-4-A 0.4040382 0.1556805
```

Thank's for the help.

Comment: `df[grepl("^LE", df$Name),]` or `dplyr::filter(df, grepl("^LE", df$Name))`

Comment: Using regex like @r2evans suggests seems most direct. You can also split the `df$Name` column using string functions and then group by the 'common' parts.

Comment: Do you mean group by the first two letters? `split(df, substr(df$Name, 1, 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stringr can help solve this too if you want to stick in the tidyverse world.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Name,'LE'))

    Name                  x                 y
1 LE-3-C  0.632601346894576 0.573187971758856
2 LE-4-A -0.818879986489542 0.284050547258268
```